# Gps android same point after moving

Tags: android, gps

Gps is working fine but when i am idle at one place for about 1 or 2 hours and if i start moving but the gps is taking the previous location where am before 1 hour its not changing.

Question when i am moving without any stops gps is locating correct but if i stop for some time and move... then the location doesn't change.
Please help me out of this.Thanks in advance.

```
   if(isGPSEnabled)
        {
            try
            {
                 if (location == null) {
             locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                      ll =    new LocationListener() {

                            public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) 
                  {

                                try {
                                       location = loc;
                                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                     logFile log=new logFile();

                                    dt = location.getTime();
                                     log.createFile("Location Changed GPS:"+latitude+""+longitude+"time:"+dt);
                                    setdateAndtime(dt);


                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                     String errMsg= e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage();
                                      logFile log=new logFile();
                                      log.createFile("Error in GPS TRACKER When Location Changed"+errMsg+"\n");
                                }

                         }

                            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

                            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

                            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                                    Bundle extras) {}
                        });
             if(locationManager!=null)
             {
                   location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                   if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        dt = location.getTime();

                        setdateAndtime(dt);

                         logFile log=new logFile();
                            log.createFile("Location From GPS:"+latitude+" "+longitude+"time:"+dt+":"+ location.getProvider()+
                                    location);
                            stopUsingGPS();
                    }
                   else
                   {
                      logFile log=new logFile();
                      log.createFile("GPS NULL");
                   }
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

when you stop some where check the GPS icon in notification bar whether its blinking or steady fixed.

1. if its blinking that means your GPS signal is lost and trying to get
   location from satellite.
2. if its fixed means you are getting updated location.

condition 1 can be occurred when you are under high-tension voltage line or inside building or you are underground or no satellite in reach.

to boost up your gps search always try to use A-GPS.

Comment: Yes i went inside building after that my gps stopped locating and when i came outside its not showing the correct location and its showing the same location like am inside the building.ofcourse this code go and search for A-GPS right? am not sure.can you  tell me how to boast A-GPS?

Comment: its obvious to take some time for GPS to be fixed. for better result you must have to wait for GPS to be fixed. Otherwise you will get either network location or last known location.

Comment: Yes u r right but its taking so much of time like 1 hour..i came outside building before 1 hour and roaming here and there traveled around 10 km also... even now also its showing the same.

Comment: same happens with me in one of my project but not fixed till now. Because this thing is quite logical.

Comment: so is there any other way to fix this issue...looking for other members to give me an answer pls...